# Upload images in file section using Shopify API in Python

Tags: python, file, upload, shopify

I have a Shopify API credentials I want to use file upload API of Shopify to upload images in file section using Python.

I tried to write a code in Python to upload images in file section of Shopify but unable to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.